# Protected sheet - The second copy paste results in cell locked

Tags: excel

Hi have a protected spreadsheet. A cell in unlocked and it is where the user is supposed to copy&paste an id-number. The id number is copy-pasted from the browser.

The first copy-paste works fine. However, the second copy-paste does not work. When data is copy-pasted in the cell from Chrome, the cell gets locked.

Any trick to avoid this issue?

Comment: Can you provide any more details? What is the existing code to lock/unlock cells, for example?

Comment: There's no code. I just right click the cell, and then "Format Cells" -> "Protection" and the untick "Locked"

Comment: You can find workaround here: http://superuser.com/a/524740

Comment: This is cool, but it doesn't work on my side.

Comment: As @BrakNicku suggested that is an expected behavior for which [a workaround exists](http://superuser.com/questions/392528/why-does-pasting-into-an-unprotected-cell-in-excel-protect-it/524740#524740)